# DataRow.AcceptChanges() for single field c#

Tags: .net, winforms, datatable

I have an issue in Infragistics Winforms Ultragrid that is bound to a `DataTable`. I need to save the value of a single field in a row. Right now, if I simply assign `DataRow.A = 1` and don't do `DataRow.AcceptChanges()`, value of the particular cell A is lost if I click off that row. If I do call `DataRow.AcceptChanges()`, all the cells get saved which I do not want, because I want other cells to reset.
So question is, how to retain the value of a single cell in a datarow?

Answer (score 0):

Use **AfterCellUpdate Event**. Let's say if name of your grid is "MyUltraGrid" then event declaration will go like following:

```
using Infragistics.Shared;
using Infragistics.Win;
using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid;
using System.Diagnostics;

private void MyUltraGrid_AfterCellUpdate(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs e)
{
    //1. Save the value of the cell in database 
    //2. Do not refresh data in grid
}
```